# Conditional Graph in grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, grob

Is there a way to use a structure like

```
grid.arrange(
    ifelse(somecondition,graph1,graph2),
    ifelse(somecondition2,graph3,graph4),
    ncol=2
)
```

where `graphX` is either a plot (created with `ggplot2`)  or a grob defined previously. It looks like `ifelse` evaluates the `grob` object to something else (a dataframe ?) before printing so `grid.arrange` doesn't get the right input to work properly.

I also tried to store all the graph objects in a collection and use that within `grid.arrange` but  coudn't get a proper data structure to work nicely.

Comment: you should use `if() ... else ...` , not `ifelse`. It may also be easier to store the objects in a list, and pass that to the `grobs=` argument of `grid.arrange`

Comment: Thks for your help. the `if() ... else ...` works. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

I tried storing the objects in a list using `myList <- c(myList,additionalGraph)` but as the graphs are interpreted as lists themselves, it didn't pan out. Any better way to go about the list route ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `if() ... else ...`, not `ifelse`,

```
p1 = qplot(1,1)
p2 = qplot(1,2)
p3 = qplot(1,3)
p4 = qplot(1,4)

grid.arrange(
    if(1 == 2) p1 else p2,
    if(3 == 3) p3 else p4,
    ncol=2
)
```

If you want to store them in a list first,

```
pl = list(if(1 == 2) p1 else p2, if(3 == 3) p3 else p4)
grid.arrange(grobs=pl, ncol=2)
```